# Checking whether Internet can be accessed without the user having to log in or agree to terms first via the browser

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android app that checks for active internet access when it is being launched for the first time on a user's device. This is because the app makes API calls and then loads some corresponding content and I wanted the app to avoid fetching any gibberish content.

There are some things I want to identify and explain here:

I do know how to check for Internet Connectivity. But the real problem is when the user is opening/accessing the app on a Wi-Fi hotspot at say, for example,  Starbucks or a corporate organization, where the phone indicates that it is connected to the Internet, but the user would have to be enter a password or agree to some terms via the browser to access the internet. I want to know if the internet could be accessed without any such hurdles. Is there a way to check if there is such active internet access?

I have tried the following, but this isn't a reliable solution:

Make a request to http://www.google.com. If there is a redirect, alert the user that there seems to no active internet access. 
This is probably going to fail, if the app is being accessed outside the US, where the redirect would be to http://www.google.co.cr for instance. But, the phone is still having internet access.

**UPDATE ONE:** *I have tried implementing this check the way it has been described in the link provided by @CommonsWare. However, the same problem identified above seems to persist. Moreover, the check takes 3-4 seconds and considering this has to be done everytime the connectivity changes, such a check would be detrimental for an app. Hence, if anyone has an efficient solution for this problem, please do let me know. In the meanwhile however, to ensure my app doesn't crash in such situations, I have put in some processing to verify that the data received is in the right format while making api calls*

**UPDATE TWO:** *Here is the solution based on @CommonsWare's suggestion. This might take 0.5 - 15 seconds, depending on the strength of the connection:*

```
    public class InternetCheck {

        public static boolean ActiveInternetExists() {

            boolean internetAccessExists = false;

            //make the android homepage as the requested url
            //this is a critical decision point.
            //the belief here is that this url can be accessed all around the world
            String urlToBeAccessed = "http://www.android.com/";

            final int TIMEOUT_VALUE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 6000;

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urlToBeAccessed);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //set the respective timeouts for the connection
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE_IN_MILLISECONDS);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE_IN_MILLISECONDS);

                //the redirect check is valid only after the response headers have been received
                //this is triggered by the getInputStream() method
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                //check if the urls of the requested and landing pages are equal
                //if yes, then we don't have a redirect
                if (url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost())) 
                    internetAccessExists =  true;
            } 

            //any sort of exception is considered as a redirect.
            //more specific exceptions such as SocketTimeOutException and IOException can be handled as well
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
            finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            return internetAccessExists;
        }

}
```

*More to come with relevance to android...*

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html -- see "Handling Network Sign-On" section.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will look into it and I let you know once I succeed. Also, I must tell you that I am overwhelmed to receive a response from a person of your caliber. I have heard a lot of great things about you from various people.

Comment: Um, thanks! Note that I haven't tried what is written up in the linked-to JavaDocs. It presumably works, though perhaps not on all Android versions, so be sure to test it going back as far as you are planning on supporting your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Please look at the update.

Comment: @Abhijit I don't see how it's avoidable--if you have your own site you're trying to access, have a non-redirecting link that you can ping.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Thanks for the tip. That seems to be reasonable. I will work on it. Also, I am assuming that such a ping would be best done in the background using an AsyncTask

Comment: Could you please add your edits as answers?  The comments by CommonsWare should probably also be answers.